# Can't connect an application to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, devexpress

A friend of mine bought an application to manage his work years ago - from a student I guess. The app was developed with DevExpress v7.2, he bought a new computer but he couldn't make it work, so he asked me to try. I created a SQL Server and restored the database, but can't connect to the SQL Server.

This is the error I get:

[image: Link to the error I get]

I noticed in the configuration file

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings.Base_PatientConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=SERVEUR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Base_Patient;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but my instance was `./SQLEXPRESS`

I didn't know what to do !

Comment: If that new machine's name isn't `SERVEUR` - then of course that connection string isn't going to work anymore. So is SQL Server **Express** installed on the local machine? Well, then just replace the connection string with: `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Base_Patient;Integrated Security=True`

Comment: I did that and still got the same error

Comment: So, **did you** really install the **Express** edition? And if so - did you possibly choose a different **instance name** (other than the default `SQLEXPRESS`) during installation?